# What percentage of UK imports/exports were with the EU in the economic year 2015-2016?

Tags: data-request, international-trade

With the referendum over whether or not the UK should leave the EU or not I am interested to know what percentage of UK trade is made up of trade within the EU (Imports & exports).

I am aware that the UK Government currently runs a [trade deficit with the EU](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/economics/12043677/UKs-trade-deficit-in-goods-with-EU-hits-record-high.html), and a ultimately a [trade deficit](https://www.uktradeinfo.com/Statistics/OverseasTradeStatistics/Pages/OTS.aspx) in general.

**My question is, how much of UK trade is within the EU, and how much of this is imports/exports in the economic year 2015-2016?** 
An objective link proving this would be excellent.

Apologies for the 'trade deficit with EU' link being far from ideal, but as you can imagine, it is hard to find solid fact among the propaganda.

& To clarify, I do not want people's opinion on whether the UK should remain or not. I am in the process of forming my own opinion based on the objective information I come across.

And as always, thank you to those that take the time to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UK Exports 2015:](http://www.worldstopexports.com/united-kingdoms-top-import-partners/)

> The United Kingdom shipped US$460.1 billion worth of products around the globe in 2015. [...] From a continental perspective, 53.6% of UK exports by value are delivered to European trade partners while 22.5% are sold to Asian importers. United Kingdom ships another 16.1% to North America but just 2.6% to Africa.

While the total value of exports is a useful piece of information, here Europe means the continent, not the EU. Thus Norway, Switzerland and several Balkan countries are also included. It is not clear where Russia would fall under such a categorization so it is better to look at Eurostat's statistics.

In 2015 the UK's [intra-EU trade](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/International_trade_in_goods#Intra-EU_trade) share was lowest among the member states  but it was still 50%.

[image: Intra EU share]

Answer (score 0):

http://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/20160105160709/http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/itis/international-trade-in-services/2011/sty-international-trade-in-services.html

[image]
<sub>(source: [gov.uk](http://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/20160105160709/http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/resources/exportsimportsbycountry1_tcm77-305126.png))</sub>

A few percent of that is with Russia which is not in the EU, the rest of the "Europe" part is overwhelmingly EU.

http://atlas.media.mit.edu/en/profile/country/rus/

Comment: "Part of International Trade in Services, 2011 Release
Released: 28 February 2013"